# Title not Showing on any application Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can not display the title in the action bar. I have Android 7.1 and no sample displays the title. My tablet use Android 7.1. I have this problem on any sample downloaded on the Website Xamarin [ScreenShot of my tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM9uL.jpg). Is it a Xamarin bug or Is there a setting to make in a visual studio or on a tablet. The title is displayed on Xamarin Live Player but not on the tablet. Do you have an idea ?
Best Regards,
Kévin

Comment: Are you setting the title from the title attribute in the xaml of your contentpage?

Comment: Attach a minimal code example to your question.

Comment: thank you for your first comment. I did a test with the official source code here https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/ Its the same example that i used on my screenshot.

Comment: Do you use Xamarin.Forms? Make sure to wrap the page into a `NavigationPage` like this `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourMainPage());` in App.xaml.cs to get titles displayed.

Comment: Yes I have already tried to adding this code on the App.css for this app https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/
But i have this error : System.Exception: Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time

public App ()
  {
   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPageCS());
        } an idea or an example to implement this would be perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin, Title appears in the Navigation bar / Action Bar in Android.

Change code in the App.xaml.cs constructor so that a NavigationPage object is created:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

Or, read this link [Xamarin Navigation by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=windows#page-navigation)